# Add a grid to an "ecdfplot" in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice, r-grid, ecdf

I am using the latticeExtra library "ecdfplot" to plot my error.  I want to add gridlines.

The following does not seem to work:

```
ecdfplot(err)
grid(ny=10)
```

It gives the following (gridless) result:
[image]

I really would love to give a "graphical summary" where the quantiles are indicated by lines, and their intersections with the data are shown on the x-axis.

Can you tell me how to add gridlines?
How about adding vertical lines at a particular x-location?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the a parameter in `ecdfplot()` like `panel = function(...) { panel.ecdfplot(...); panel.grid() }`?

Comment: Luke - I am unfamiliar with those.  Can you provide a decent example link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the argument `axis = axis.grid`

```
require(latticeExtra)

data(singer, package = "lattice")
ecdfplot(~height, data = singer, add=TRUE, axis = axis.grid, par.settings = theEconomist.theme())
```

[image]